# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vaex.remote'

Tags: python, anaconda, vaex

I was trying to install the `vaex` application from Anaconda Navigator, but it fails to launch with an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vaex.remote'`. Everything is installed, and I even reinstalled everything, with no better results:

```sh
~$ conda install -c conda-forge vaex vaex-core vaex-hdf5 vaex-ui vaex-server vaex-ml --force-reinstall --yes
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/myusername/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - vaex
    - vaex-core
    - vaex-hdf5
    - vaex-ml
    - vaex-server
    - vaex-ui



Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import vaex.remote
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e480b6348be7> in <module>
----> 1 import vaex.remote

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vaex.remote'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very frequent and debated issue on Anaconda for that specific module.

I suggest this approach that is from this thread, where Jovan is giving a very good answer: https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/464

Quoting it below:

Create a new conda env and install thru conda forge:

```
conda create --name vaex_env
source activate vaex_enc
```

Then simply install vaex through conda(forge).

```
conda install vaex -c conda-forge
```

This will install all necessary dependencies as well.

This should work!

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. You could expect that it would work better on its own environment, but that wasn't the case.